# duplicate member form

Tags: php, javascript

i have a booking form as you see bellow:

```
<table border=0> 
    <tr>  
            <td colspan="2"><h2>Book Now</h2>   </td>  
            </tr> 
        <tr>  
            <td width="139"> Select Date (dd/mm/yy):</td>  
            <td width="351"> <input type="text"  id="datepicker"> </td>  
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>Select Category:</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><select name="orgSelect" class="orgSelect">
<option value="0">----Select CAtegory----</option>
<option value="1">CAtegory 1</option>
<option value="2">CAtegory 2</option>
</select></td>
<tr>
<td>Select Product:</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
          </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><select name="terrSelect" class="terrSelect">
<option value="0" class="static">----Select Product----</option>
<option value="1" class="sub_1">Product1</option>
<option value="2" class="sub_1">Product2</option>
</select>
   </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>  
            <td> Number of Persons</td>  
            <td>
              <select name="persons" id="persons">
                <option>select</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
              </select></td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td><strong>Information:</strong></td>  
            <td>&nbsp;</td>  
        </tr>
         <tr>  
            <td>1st Member: </td>  
            <td>&nbsp;</td>  
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>First Name:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="date" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Last Name:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="date" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Email:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="date" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Phone</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="date" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Mobile Phone</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="date" value=""></td>
         </tr> 
    </table>
    <p>Add Member</p>
```

But i have a problem, in the end where it says "Add MEmber" i liked to duplicate the booking form, for a second our third person to book too, how can i make this duplicate the booking form?

Comment: Please explain more about duplicate for, Why to duplicate for second or third person,if you want to book for more than one person than you can add field like name of first person, etc

Comment: Thr reasons are more than this, because the booking are made by groups, this is how have to be :S

Comment: What you seem to want is quite easy. Try some quick javascript tutorial and try to do it, If you face problems comeback here and ask. It is just html.

Comment: Yes, could someone give a example?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to archive this. One easy way is to submit all data to the server, where the whole form gets rebuild. Doing this on javascript-side could be done with templating (I assume you use jquery).

The serverside-solution (as the final submitting) requires, that your input-names are formed wisly.

Example:

```
data[members][{$memberId}][name]
```

If you want to determine, if the form was submitted in its final form, or just to add a member, you can form the submit-buttons like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn[submit]" value="submit booking" />
<input type="submit" name="btn[add]" value="submit booking" />
```

On php-side this could be determined by:

```
$btnType = isset($_REQUEST['btn']) && is_array($_REQUEST['btn']) ? array_shift(array_keys($_REQUEST['btn'])) : 'submit';
```

There are still improvements to apply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple table bodies, this will make the solution very simple and also work in cases where javascript is disabled in the client's browser:

```
<body>

<table border=0 id="table1">

    <tbody>
        <tr>  
            <td colspan="2"><h2>Book Now</h2>   </td> 
            ...
            <select name="persons" id="persons" onchange="change_persons(this.value)">
            ...
            <td><strong>Information:</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1st Member: </td>
            ...
            <td>Mobile Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile1" value=""></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2nd Member: </td>
            ...
            <td>Mobile Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile2" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3rd Member: </td>
            ...
            <td>Mobile Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile3" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function change_persons(show) {
    var bodies = document.getElementById('table1').tBodies;
    for (var i=1, l=bodies.length; i<l; i++) {
        bodies[i].style.display = (i<=show)? 'block':'none';
    }
}
change_persons(1); // at startup we show only 1 person
//--></script>

</body>
```

Full html [here](http://pastebin.com/TNt9dhYi)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just not to confuse you, I just realized that I used Stano and Eric's html for the table layout.

I am definetly recommending to use jQuery, it will make things a lot easier.  You can add it to your page with the line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I would then use a button for the Add Member option:

```
<button id='addMember'>Add new member</button>
```

You should also give an id to your table

```
<table id='bigTable' border=0>
```

in a js file, you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var currentMember = 2;
 $(function() {
  $('#addMember').click(function(event) {
   $('<tbody>')
    .attr('id', 'subTableMember'+currentMember);
    .appendTo('#bigTable');
   $('<tr>')
    .attr('id', 'tableRowMember'+currentMember);
    .appendTo('#subTableMember'+currentMember);
   $('<td>')
    .html(currentMember+'th member')
    .appendTo('#tableRowMember'+currentMember);
   $('<td>')
    .html('<input type="text" name="mobile'+currentMember+'">');
    .appendTo('#tableRowMember'+currentMember);
   currentMember++;
  });
 });
});
```

I haven't tested the code but it should help you get started.

ANOTHER EDIT:
If forgot the server part.  On your php code, you can now use something like:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
 if(substr($key, 0, 6) == 'mobile') {
  //This is a member mobile, add it to your DB or whatever
  echo $key.' => '.$val;
 }
}
```

This way, a user can add all the members he wants and you can all process them.